# How to get all OU in Ad with parameter (description blank ) - without description?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am new in Powershell. Wanna to get all Organizational Units in Domain without description. ( description - blank )

I have script which gets all users with paramater "null description"
But i need to find OUs.

$NoDescrUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq "True" ) -and (description -notlike '*')} -Properties Description

Can anyone help to modify this script for OU-s?

Answer (score 2):

```
$NoDescrAD = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {(description -notlike "*")} -Properties description
```